# Windows 10 Disk Usage 99% most of the time

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, task-manager

I turned On my laptop running Windows 10 Creators update, it was running fine but suddenly become slow , so i looked in taskmanager and found the Disk usage is most of the time is 99% as you can see the screen shot after sorting it is showing windows update is the culprit but it is using just 1.5 MB/s then who is using all the disk. Any ideas

[image: Taskmanager]

[image]

Comment: In the bottom left corner of the Processes tab, does it say "More Details" or "Less Details"?  If you go to the Performance tab, choose "Open Resource Monitor", and then the "Disk" tab, click the down arrow by "Disk Activity" and then click on column headers to sort.

Comment: Now Disk utilization has come down to 14% and holding . May be there was some background process which was hogging Disk, will check it from time to time maybe i can give more information

Comment: simply use a SSD, HDDs are slow